# Quartz.Net Job stuck on pending status

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz

I have created an array of jobs with JobChainingJobListener, so when one job starts or fails the second job starts running.

I have the next scenario:
I start the first job, then recycle the application pool. When the application starts again, the job that started the execution earlier finishes but the next job doesn't start.

What can cause this issue?